# What's the parsing rule of Google Cloud Error Report?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

I log the error to *Google StackDriver Logging*.
But the *Google Cloud Error Reporting* doesn't recognise it (work for others).
Is my formatting so different that error reporter can not recognise it ?
What's the parsing rule of Google Cloud Error Report ?

The logs is:

```
02:05:12 ERROR application          -

! @78in3pjc5 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/api/news/page/1] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NonNullableColumnRead: SQL `NULL` read at column 5 (JDBC type Array) but mapping is to a non-Option type; use Option here. Note that JDBC column indexing is 1-based.]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:247)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:178)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:363)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:361)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$recoverWith$1(Future.scala:413)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:37)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
Caused by: doobie.util.invariant$NonNullableColumnRead: SQL `NULL` read at column 5 (JDBC type Array) but mapping is to a non-Option type; use Option here. Note that JDBC column indexing is 1-based.
    at doobie.util.meta$Meta.unsafeGetNonNullable(meta.scala:50)
    at doobie.util.composite$Composite$$anon$6$$anon$7.$anonfun$get$3(composite.scala:121)
    at doobie.util.composite$Composite$$anon$6$$anon$7.$anonfun$get$3$adapted(composite.scala:121)
    at doobie.util.kernel$Kernel$$anon$6.$anonfun$get$3(kernel.scala:80)
    at doobie.util.kernel$Kernel$$anon$6.$anonfun$get$3$adapted(kernel.scala:80)
    at doobie.util.kernel$Kernel$$anon$6.$anonfun$get$3(kernel.scala:80)
    at doobie.util.kernel$Kernel$$anon$6.$anonfun$get$3$adapted(kernel.scala:80)
    at doobie.util.kernel$Kernel$$anon$6.$anonfun$get$3(kernel.scala:80)
    at doobie.util.kernel$Kernel$$anon$6.$anonfun$get$3$adapted(kernel.scala:80)
    at doobie.util.kernel$Kernel$$anon$6.$anonfun$get$3(kernel.scala:80)
```

Comment: Can you provide some additional context? How are you creating the log?

Comment: @J.LValtueña I am using GKE Kubernetes with stackdriver logging enabled.

Comment: It seems like you have a null value in a column that doesn't admit null values. Can you check that?

Comment: yes, but I want the error to appear on error report.

Comment: Check this, i think it can be useful for you. - https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/tasks/creating-logs  AND  https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the full log entry (e.g. as it appears then fully expanded in https://console.cloud.google.com/logs)?

The problem doesn't appear to be in the format of the stacktrace. The error is captured by if I:

1. go to the [Cloud Console API explorer](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.events/report?apix=true)
2. enter "projects/[PROJECT_NAME]" for `projectName`
3. copy your content (i.e. starting from 02:05:12)
4. replace newlines with "\n"
5. paste that as a `message` in the Request Body
6. hit "Execute"